# Get Single Doc Firebase 9

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Im trying to get a single doc and delete it but im having trouble.
Ive followed a tutorial exactly but I keep getting the error 'doc is not a function' on the first instance of doc

This is the code im using...

```
const deleteRef = doc(db, 'users', id); 

getDoc(deleteRef).then((doc) => { 
     console.log(doc.data(), doc.id) 
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

In another site I have built, the word doc is yellow in VS code
But in this site im building now doc is going blue

I do have doc being imported from the Firebase SDK in both sites.

Just realised if I write doc() at the top of my code its yellow but if its lower down its blue

Answer (score 2):

I'm not totally sure how your complete code looks like. But try naming multiple variables/function with different names to reduce any confusion. Try refactoring the code as shown below:

```
import { doc, getDoc } from "firebase/firestore"

const deleteRef = doc(db, 'users', id); 

getDoc(deleteRef).then((snapshot) => { 
  console.log(snapshot.data(), snapshot.id) 
});
```

If you still get the same error, please check if you have `doc` declared anywhere else and share the complete code.